# How to configure Rails API to use cookies for web clients and tokens for mobile apps?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, devise-token-auth, devise-jwt

I'm developing a Rails app (with Devise) to expose an API to be consumed by both web clients (React SPA) and mobile clients (iOS and Android).

For web clients I'd like to use cookie authentication to avoid the problem of where to securely store the token (I would also use a cookie to pass the CSRF token to the web client).

For mobile apps I'd like to use some kind of token authentication to simplify and avoid the need for cookies and CSRF on those platforms.

I looked briefly at the popular gems [devise-token-auth](https://github.com/lynndylanhurley/devise_token_auth) and [devise-jwt](https://github.com/waiting-for-dev/devise-jwt) which add token support to Devise but the documentation for both (see [here](https://devise-token-auth.gitbook.io/devise-token-auth/faq#can-i-use-this-gem-alongside-standard-devise) and [here](https://github.com/waiting-for-dev/devise-jwt#session-storage-caveat)) suggest that cookie auth and token auth won't work within the same controller.

How would you configure a Rails API to use cookies for web clients and tokens for mobile apps?

Comment: I'm also working on this at the moment!
(Simple Token Auth)[https://github.com/gonzalo-bulnes/simple_token_authentication] Seems to indicate support for both. However it is currently incompatible with Rails 7 and Ruby 3. 
Their approach is to check for a token first and then fall back to Devise based on the token auth gist in the devise Wiki. 
At this point I'm leaning towards rolling my own but I'd like to avoid that if possible!